# Updating one table to another with c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, dataset, repeater

I have these 2 asp.net repeaters that I bind with data from datasets. User table has 13 records and operator table has 8 records. So if I choose to add one row from the user table to operator table, I want that row to be removed and inserted to the other directly without redirecting the page. How should I solve this?

C#:

```
                var userDetailsList = new List<ContactPartial>();
                TellusAPI.TellusUserDetails userDetails;

            var operators = _administrationSystem.GetOperatorsInformation(userId); //First dataset
            var users = webSearch.DoSearchForNameAndNumber(userId, txtSearchForOperator.Text, false, "", "", false, false, out userDetails); //Second dataset

            if (users != null)
            {
                userDetailsList = users.Select(user => new ContactPartial(user)).ToList();

                     var query = (from n in nodes.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                     join o in operators.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                     on n.Field<int>("NodeIndex") equals o.Field<int>("NodeIndex")
                     select new
                     {
                         ID = o.Field<long>("ID"),
                         FirstName = o.Field<string>("FirstName"),
                         SurName = o.Field<string>("SurName"),
                         NodeName = n.Field<string>("NodeName"),
                         TranslatorName = o.Field<string>("TranslatorName"),
                         EMail = o.Field<string>("EMail"),
                         LastLogin = o.Field<object>("LastLogin")

                     }).ToList();
              }

        rptList.DataSource = query.OrderBy(name => name.FirstName); //First repeater
        rptList.DataBind();

        rptAdd.DataSource = userDetailsList.OrderBy(name => name.FirstName); //Second repeater
        rptAdd.DataBind();
```